# Appgyver Steroids and Android push notifications even possible?

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, steroids

Been trying to get Steroids working with push notifications on Android and keep hitting a brick wall.

As far as I can see, there's no official support for https://github.com/AppGyver/PushPlugin, and the [Urban Airship](https://academy.appgyver.com/categories/16-steroids-addons/contents/139-urban-airship-addon-installation) addon is currently iOS only.

When I set the custom plugin in the build configuration, I get some pretty nasty [build errors](http://pastebin.com/BTB2tuRk). This is with just a freshly created and deployed steroids project, and just generally can't even get to the point where I have a build to play around with push notifications :(

There was some rumbling about the devs prioritising pushplugin around Dec 2013, but unsure if that ever actually materialised?

So I have:

`steroids create pushTest`

`steroids deploy`

...then I goto https://cloud.appgyver.com/applications/, configure my app in the android tab by adding this to the custom plugins...

```
[
  {"source":"https://github.com/AppGyver/PushPlugin.git"}
]
```

Then run a build on 4.0.2. I am trying a scanner build, tried ARM, x86, and both, and keep coming back with build issues as above, or on some of the other forks ones that are a bit more vague, but I suspect those forks to be old.

**So my question:** Is it even possible to get push notifications working with Steroids under Android?

Comment: Yes it is possible. You might have to modify or build your own plugin, but it's possible. Take a look at other Cordova push notification plugins for Android though, like the [PhoneGap Build Version](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin), as Cordova plugins work on Steroids.

Comment: That gives me `Your Cordova plugin tries to include a library (eg. android-support-xx.jar) which is already included. Remove reference to the offending library from plugin.xml of your Cordova plugin.` so I forked it, and removed that line in the plugin.xml, which then also failed the build with `Either one of your PNG image assets has invalid format or Build Service encountered this issue: https://github.com/AppGyver/steroids/issues/279 -- If your build does not succeed on a retry, try re-uploading the mentioned image asset.` but this is a fresh project, with only default assets anyways

Comment: also @AndrewLively this is my first time using steroids, just trying to get a tech demo sorted before I commit to using it. Not having much luck at the moment though, and creating my own plugin seems overkill

Comment: Your build error `Failed to read key from keystore` is caused by either having an invalid Android keystore, incorrect keystore password or invalid keystore alias. If you don't know the correct values and this is only a test build, you may create a new keystore and upload it to the AppGyver build service (with a valid keystore password and alias).

Answer (score 1):

There's now an officially supported fork of the Push Plugin which works with the AppGyver Android Client: https://github.com/AppGyver/PushNotifications

The minimum required version for the Android client is 4.0.4-edge3.

Please see the [Push Notification guide](http://docs.appgyver.com/tooling/push-notifications/) for instructions how to create the required iOS Certificates and the Google GCM API key.

Comment: And how you receive notifications when you have the app closed (not in background)? The plugin doesn't create any service it does work only in foreground and background not once killed.